# Filter DirectoryEntry objects based on objectClass

Tags: c#, active-directory, treeview, directoryentry

I have created an Active Directory object browser using the WPF TreeView element, but I want to only add OUs to my tree. I feel like I am very close, here is my code thus far for my Item.Expanded event handler.  This all works, but it adds every object, whereas I want to filter out non-OU objects:

```
 private void item_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource;
        item.Items.Clear();

        DirectoryEntry de;
        if (item.Tag is Domain)
        {
            Domain dom = (Domain)item.Tag;
            de = dom.GetDirectoryEntry();
        }
        else
        {
            de = (DirectoryEntry)item.Tag;
        }

        try
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry dirEntry in de.Children)
            {
                TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
                newItem.Tag = dirEntry;
                newItem.Header = dirEntry.Name;
                newItem.Items.Add("*");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Exception!
            textBox.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I had something like

```
if (dirEntry.Properties["objectClass"].Value.ToString() == "organizationalUnit")
```

but that didn't work (objectClass is an array of values, so comparing to a string didn't work).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (dirEntry.Properties["objectClass"].Contains("organizationalUnit"))
```

Got me what I wanted.  Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

The more general way is to use `DirectorySearcher`:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel;
foreach (SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
{
    DirectoryEntry dirEntry = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
    //your code here
}
```